# How to split a string, keeping order and the reason for the split?

Tags: c#

I am trying to split an HTML string into a Dictionary, where I keep the text, and what the HTML element was

For example, with this input

```
var input = "This is <b>bold</b> where as <i>this is italic</i>. This is the last sentence";
```

I would like the following output

```
{"This is ", "None"},
{"bold", "Bold"},
{" where as ", "None"},
{"this is italic", "italic"},
{". This is the last sentence", "None"},
```

I can share my effort, but it's fairly pointless as I can't get it to work, and my approach feels impossible to scale.

```
internal Dictionary<string, string> SplitTextByHtmlTags(string input)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var splitText = new List<string>();
    var split = Split(input, "b");

    foreach (var bold in split)
    {
        var italics = Split(bold, "i");
        splitText.AddRange(italics);
    }

    foreach (var bold in splitText)
    {
        var underlines= Split(bold, "u");
        splitText.AddRange(underlines);
    }

    return result;
}

private IEnumerable<string> Split(string input, string htmlEleName)
{
    return input.Split("<"+htmlEleName+">").Select(s => s.Split("</"+htmlEleName+">")).ToList();
}
```

As I said, the above does not return the right value nor does it work.

Comment: `Dictionary<K, V>` doesn't guarantee any order

Comment: Thanks. I have removed that constraint :)

Comment: Another reason against dictionary is that all keys must be *distinct*, e.g. there's no way to turn `"A<i>B<i>A"` into dictionary as described in the question (we have *two* `"A"` keys).

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser?

Comment: @41686d6564 good question. I think because in this case, I am unable to do it so it's more of a learning exercise than just getting the right result :)

Comment: What about a scenario with <b><i>bold and italic</i></b>

Comment: @DRapp, That is also possible; but since I would need to focus on learning, it's OK to skip that. I'm hoping also, to be able to work that part out myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input text is always this simple (no nested tags, no attributes, comments, etc.), this is fairly easy to achieve using [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). Otherwise, I would stick to using an [HTML parser](http://%5BC#%20library%20for%20parsing%20HTML?%5D(https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10773/67933)).

Here's a full example:

```
var result = new List<(string text, string styling)>();

string input = 
    "This is <b>bold</b> where as <i>this is italic</i>. This is the last sentence";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^<]+|<([bi])>([^<]+)</\1>");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    // If neither `<b>` nor `<i>` was found.
    if (!match.Groups[1].Success)
    {
        result.Add((match.Value, "None"));
    }
    else
    {
        string styling = (match.Groups[1].Value == "b" ? "Bold" : "Italic");
        result.Add((match.Groups[2].Value, styling));
    }
}
```

The example above creates a list of [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) instead of a dictionary (which won't work in this case for reasons mentioned in the comments. The ValueTuple here has two string items. You might consider using an `enum` instead of a string for the styling.

**Explanation of the Regex pattern:**

- `[^<]+` - Match one or more characters other than '<'.
- `|` - Or.
- `<([bi])>` - Match either 'b' or 'i' enclosed in angle brakets and capture the letter in group 1.
- `([^<]+)` - Match one or more characters other than '<' and capture them in group 2.
- `</\1>` - Match a closing HTML tag (i.e., `</..>`) with the letter that was captured in group 1.

---

If you need to support other HTML tags, replace `[bi]` with something like `(?:[biu]|div|span|etc)` in the pattern above (or simply use `\w+` to support any arbitrary tag). Then, you can have a dictionary that returns the "nice name" for each tag name:

```
var tags = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "b", "Bold" },
    { "i", "Italic" },
    { "u", "Underline" },
};
```

Then, you can use it in the `else` branch like this:

```
if (!tags.TryGetValue(match.Groups[1].Value, out string tag))
    tag = match.Groups[1].Value;
result.Add((match.Groups[2].Value, tag));
```

Comment: VERY NICE solution, especially the clarification of how the regular expression pattern is applied to their scenario.  New one for me about using the \1 to use whatever was found in the first group later in the string... Again, VERY NICE.

Comment: See, this is an amazing answer. I'm glad you asked why not just use a parser and it's helped me to explain it's about learning. I have 0 questions about this because it is explained so well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cs
internal Dictionary<string, string> SplitTextByHtmlTags(string input)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //  Iterating through a string
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        //  Detecting the opening of the tag
        if (input[i] == '<')
        {
            string 
                tag = "",       //  Name of the tag
                content = "";   //  Content of the tag

            //  Iterating over the tag
            for (int j = i+1; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                /**
                    * If alphabetic characters are being iterated over,
                    * then, most likely, this is the name of the tag.
                    */
                if (!input[j].IsLetter())
                {
                    //  As soon as any character that is not a letter occurs
                    for (int k = j; k < input.Length; k++)
                    {
                        //  Looking for the end of the tag
                        if (input[k] == '>')
                        {
                            //  Sorting through the contents of the tag
                            for (int l = k+1; l < input.Length; l++)
                            {
                                if (input[l] != '<')
                                {
                                    content += input[l];

                                    /*
                                    * We move the "cursor" of the main loop
                                    * to the place where the tag opening symbol was found.
                                    */
                                    i = l;

                                    //  We put the found values in the map
                                    result.Add(tag, content);

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else tag += input[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```